# Clear HTML login form with username textfield filled with cookie

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication, web

Good morning,
I'm doing a basic website for the university.
I should provide a login form where the user can insert username and password... If those are correct a cookie is saved with username value; thanks to this cookie, when the user closes the session and opens again the browser to login, the username field is already there (I did this with a php script inside the form).
The only problem is that the button that should clear both the textfields in the form doesn't work.

```
 <form name="f" action="controlAndErrorLogin.php" method="POST">
        <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" value=<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["username"])){echo "\"".$_COOKIE["username"]."\"";}else{echo "\"\"";}?>>
            </p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" value=""></p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="OK">
            <input type="reset" value="PULISCI" onclick="document.getElementById('username').value = '';"> 
        </p>
    </form>
```

What is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your input field is missing the `id` that you are trying to select it by.

Second, a `reset` button resets form fields to the *default* value they had specified in the initial HTML. You specified the user name in there, not an empty value - so *that’s* what the field will get reset to.

Third, `.value = ''` only resets the current value of the element, but not the *default* value. You need to set the actual `defaultValue` property, to achieve that.

```html
<form name="f" action="controlAndErrorLogin.php" method="POST">
  <p>Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="foo"></p>
  <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" value=""></p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
    <input type="reset" value="PULISCI" 
           onclick="document.getElementById('username').defaultValue = '';">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add attribute id="username" in the input tag with name="username"